# How can I enable the dropdown notification bar on lockscreen on the Asus Zenfone 2?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, notification-bar, xposed-framework, asus-zenfone-2, x86-processors

On my old phone (Samsung I9305), I was able to enable the dropdown notification bar while the phone was locked by using [this Xposed module.](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.labtech.mod)

However, it doesn't work on my Zenfone 2. (Running 5.0, rooted with Xposed Framework.) Yes, I have activated the module, rebooted, activated the setting and then rebooted again.

[Several other Xposed modules](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/150158/131868) do work.

Maybe it's because of incompatibility with 5.0 or x86?

In any case, is there any way to enable it on the lock screen?

*By the way, the bounty notice says "credible sources." Obviously, that's **not** required. It just needs to work. Should probably have used to "draw attention" tag.*

Comment: comments [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/150147/131553) indicate that it is x86 issue. Maybe you can try with [Xposed Module x86](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/development/unofficial-xposed-lollipop-rom-t3126306) to see if the module works?

Comment: @beeshyams I misunderstand  your comment at first. I thought you were linking to some Xposed Module that would enhance compatability with x86 for other apps. To clarify, I have successfully installed Xposed Framework, as well as [several other modules](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/150158/131868).

Comment: I am aware by your comment linking modules tried. Uninstalling that and installing framework using this is the option i was suggesting, since this appears to be specifically tailored for your chipset peculiarities. Of course, you don't know if all the modules you use now will work or not.  Reasons for believing that this framework is different from regular ones 1. My last device was Huawei, and because of heavily Tweaked UI, only  a *modded framework* would work or a very early version (2.5.1) of regular framework 2.  In the linked thread, do not see any updates to the OP to date // cont'd//

Comment: And that supports #1 .  I can't make out of it is modded or a early framework that is offered.  You can always take a Nandroid and try this after uninstalling regular framework. 3.Besides, it specifically claims Lollipop support for *all devices running Intel processor*

Comment: @beeshyams The framework I have now is already a special x86 build.

Comment: This version is *ported* for your device specially, as mentioned in the first line of OP. Unless i am wrong, you are meaning it is special because it is designed for your chipset. But being ported may have taken care of some peculiarities of your device and your desired mod is also not updated for long and may just work with this ported framework. Upto you to explore. I can't test

Comment: @beeshyams Right. I misunderstood your comments. Was a bit tired yesterday, sorry. I've tried it now. I uninstalled my previous Xposed, and tried installing the one you linked to. Unfortunately, flashing Xposed via `adb` doesn't work with my device (no idea why.) (I get [this](http://pastebin.com/zBZYAJJb) output, but the phone doesn't reboot or anything.) It was the same way with my previous Xposed. I had to flash via recovery. The thread you linked to doesn't supply any `.zip` for recovery flashing.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks for trying! Do you think you could also take a look at [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/150319/131868)?

Comment: I wish i could but can't as i have no knowledge of Linux and just manage to get by using basic commands.  Suggest you ping for help in chat room for Linux pros to help you. All the best. Doesn't hurt to ask on XDA thread too

Comment: @beeshyams I actually managed to flash it via `adb` now, but it gave a bootloop. No big deal,  just restored the firmware.  Thanks for the suggestion anyway.